# Save list within data.table to csv and load it back (R)

Tags: r, list, csv, shiny, data.table

I have a data.table that contains a list column. It's a table I need to write every session so after re-opening the application I can go back to the most recent state.

The table looks as follows:

```
data.table(`ID Universal` = character(), StartDate = as.Date(character()), EndDate = as.Date(character()), 
                      BOX = character(), `Days in Period` = numeric(), 
                      `Workdays in Period` = integer(), `Present Workdays in Period` = integer(), 
                      `Days not present in Period` = list())
```

The writing part I tried to solve by using strsplit:

```
dt.absent <- data.table(do.call("rbind", strsplit(as.character(global$dt.requests$`Days not present in Period`), ",")))
dt.req_csv <- cbind(global$dt.requests[, -8], dt.absent)
write.csv(dt.req_csv, "Requests.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

This process seems to work as intended (also open for alternatives) but the loading part I cannot make work. I want to load the csv so it looks just like original data.table (I use the default YYYY-mm-dd date format)

Comment: If you're just going to load it back into R, is there a reason you can't just save as an R object with `saveRDS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you must save the data like an rds file, not a csv. When you use `fread` you lose factor variables and sometimes dates.

Just save it as an RDS file and reload it like that.

```
saveRDS(object, "file.rds")
object <- readRDS("file.rds")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't see the actual contents of the `data.table`, it is a little difficult to speculate on exactly what you mean by *"looks just like"*. I'm guessing it's a `POSIXt`/`Date` thing during read. Here's a workaround using `read.csv(..., colClasses=)`.

```r
### create a file
write.csv(data.table(rn=100L, nowdt=Sys.Date(), nowpsx=Sys.time()), "~/StackOverflow/WietsedeVries.csv", row.names=F)
readLines("~/StackOverflow/WietsedeVries.csv")
# [1] "\"rn\",\"nowdt\",\"nowpsx\""        "100,2020-01-13,2020-01-13 08:55:56"
```

(Note that `POSIXt` output is being affected by `options(digits.secs)`.)

Reading it in:

```r
str(read.csv("~/StackOverflow/WietsedeVries.csv"))
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ rn    : int 100
#  $ nowdt : Factor w/ 1 level "2020-01-13": 1
#  $ nowpsx: Factor w/ 1 level "2020-01-13 08:55:56": 1
str(read.csv("~/StackOverflow/WietsedeVries.csv", colClasses=c(nowdt="Date", nowpsx="POSIXct")))
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ rn    : int 100
#  $ nowdt : Date, format: "2020-01-13"
#  $ nowpsx: POSIXct, format: "2020-01-13 08:55:56"
```

(I believe that `data.table::fread` does not yet support functionality for `POSIXct` or `Date`.)

---

Notes:

- As you can see from the `readLines` output, the timestamp does not include any timezone information. If you're just worried about dates, then this is not a problem. If you always *always* ***always*** deal in the same timezone (e.g., everything is "UTC"), then this is not a problem. For everything else, however, you need to put in some more code to encode timezone information. This reduces the simplicity of using `colClasses=` (since it'll be using `as.POSIXct` without `format="..."`, so you will have to process the column manually after `read.csv(..., colClasses=c(nowpsx="character"))`).
- Since you say *"write after every session"*, you might consider instead using a database of some sort. If you want to keep it simple, then `RSQLite` still just requires a single external file on the filesystem, and you can do a bit more with a database-backed dataset than with a CSV. While SQLite doesn't itself have perfect time/date classes, I believe the `DBI`/`RSQLite` combination does a great job of doing what you need most of the time. On that note, you would probably want to include at least two more columns: some unique id (perhaps an incrementing integer) and a "created" timestamp, just for records-keeping if nothing else.